# How can I add soft body physics to multiple objects at once?

Tags: physics, soft-body

I am trying to create a "soft body physics method" on an object, but is there any method which can apply it on multiple object at once? (I am not talking about rigid body physics.)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31970/how-can-i-copy-soft-body-settings-to-other-objects/33103#33103

Answer (score 2):

This will work for any type of physics.

Select all the objects then hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and select the object you want to copy from,
this will make it the active object.

Now simply press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and select modifiers,
Since all Physics Properties are modifiers this will copy the same physics setting to all the objects

**NOTE:** This will also copy any other modifiers present on the base object.

Comment: I did NOT know that physics features were considered modifiers for this purpose. Thanks for this.